# card.io error buildNative

Tags: android, android-ndk, card.io

hei, i'm using card.io now, and i want to custom the navigation of it, so i clone the [card.io-Android-source](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source)
I follow the step there, but i'm stuck at step 6. $ ./gradlew clean assembleDebug

it shows this error, I'm using --stacktrace to run clean assembleDebug

```
make: *** [E:/Projects/Android/card.io-Android-source-master/card.io/src/main/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cardioRecognizer_tegra2/card.io-dmz/dmz_all.o] Error 1
make: *** Waiting for unfinished jobs....
C:\Users\cashlez\AppData\Local\Temp\dmz_all-e66c46.s: Assembler messages:
C:\Users\cashlez\AppData\Local\Temp\dmz_all-e66c46.s:65457: Error: r13 not allowed here -- `sub.w sp,r2,#832'
C:\Users\cashlez\AppData\Local\Temp\dmz_all-e66c46.s:71237: Error: r13 not allowed here -- `sub.w sp,r2,#1296'
C:\Users\cashlez\AppData\Local\Temp\dmz_all-e66c46.s:71351: Error: r13 not allowed here -- `sub.w sp,r2,#144'
C:\Users\cashlez\AppData\Local\Temp\dmz_all-e66c46.s:91719: Error: r13 not allowed here -- `sub.w sp,r2,#720'
C:\Users\cashlez\AppData\Local\Temp\dmz_all-e66c46.s:97244: Error: r13 not allowed here -- `sub.w sp,r2,#496'
C:\Users\cashlez\AppData\Local\Temp\dmz_all-e66c46.s:97358: Error: r13 not allowed here -- `sub.w sp,r2,#720'
clang++.exe: error: assembler command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
make: *** [E:/Projects/Android/card.io-Android-source-master/card.io/src/main/obj/local/armeabi-v7a/objs/cardioRecognizer/card.io-dmz/dmz_all.o] Error 1
make: Leaving directory `E:/Projects/Android/card.io-Android-source-master/card.io/src/main/jni'
:card.io:buildNative FAILED

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':card.io:buildNative'.
> Process 'command 'E:/Installer/android-ndk-r11c/build/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2

* Try:
Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.

* Exception is:
org.gradle.api.tasks.TaskExecutionException: Execution failed for task ':card.io:buildNative'.
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:69)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:46)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.execute(PostExecutionAnalysisTaskExecuter.java:35)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:64)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:42)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:52)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:53)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask.executeWithoutThrowingTaskFailure(AbstractTask.java:305)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.executeTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:79)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:63)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:51)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:88)
        at org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:29)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$200(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$2.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:68)
        at org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:62)
        at org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:55)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:149)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:106)
        at org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:86)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter$DefaultBuildController.run(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExecuteBuildAction.run(ExecuteBuildAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:36)
        at org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.RunBuildAction.run(RunBuildAction.java:51)
        at org.gradle.internal.Actions$RunnableActionAdapter.execute(Actions.java:171)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:237)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$ParseAndBuildAction.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:210)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.JavaRuntimeValidationAction.execute(JavaRuntimeValidationAction.java:24)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:206)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.CommandLineActionFactory$WithLogging.execute(CommandLineActionFactory.java:169)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.cli.ExceptionReportingAction.execute(ExceptionReportingAction.java:22)
        at org.gradle.launcher.Main.doAction(Main.java:33)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.EntryPoint.run(EntryPoint.java:45)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.runNoExit(ProcessBootstrap.java:54)
        at org.gradle.launcher.bootstrap.ProcessBootstrap.run(ProcessBootstrap.java:35)
        at org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain.main(GradleMain.java:23)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.BootstrapMainStarter.start(BootstrapMainStarter.java:30)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:127)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(GradleWrapperMain.java:56)
Caused by: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command 'E:/Installer/android-ndk-r11c/build/ndk-build.cmd'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecHandle$ExecResultImpl.assertNormalExitValue(DefaultExecHandle.java:365)
        at org.gradle.process.internal.DefaultExecAction.execute(DefaultExecAction.java:31)
        at org.gradle.api.tasks.AbstractExecTask.exec(AbstractExecTask.java:54)
        at org.gradle.internal.reflect.JavaMethod.invoke(JavaMethod.java:63)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.doExecute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:218)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:211)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.project.taskfactory.AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory$StandardTaskAction.execute(AnnotationProcessingTaskFactory.java:200)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:579)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:562)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:80)
        at org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:61)
        ... 47 more
```

I've edit my local.properties and change the sdk & ndk dir to my directory

and this is my cleanNative & buildNative task in build.grade card.io

```
    task cleanNative(type: Exec, description: 'Clean JNI object files') {
        commandLine "E:/Installer/android-ndk-r11c/build/ndk-build.cmd",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                'clean'
    }
    clean.dependsOn cleanNative

    task buildNative(type: Exec, description: 'Compile JNI source via NDK') {
        commandLine "E:/Installer/android-ndk-r11c/build/ndk-build.cmd",
                '-C', file('src/main/jni').absolutePath,
                '-j', Runtime.runtime.availableProcessors(),
                'all'
    }
```

the path of ndk-build.cmd is right, but still show the errors

anyone can help me? I really appreaciate :)

Comment: Please see [the relevant GitHub issue](https://github.com/card-io/card.io-Android-source/issues/60).  The card.io SDK doesn't play nicely with NDK 11.

Comment: thx a lot! finally solved

Comment: Hi @RobinRevialus Would you please let me know how you solved it?

Answer (score 0):

I am using android-ndk-r10e, it works for me